# How to output text to terminal while program piped

Tags: python, pipe

I have a program that pipes specific text into another program, which is created out of userinput. The user needs feedback which is displayed in the terminal.

The program **should** be called like this:

```
$ python inputData.py | ./otherProgram
```

However I use `sys.stderr` as a workaround, but this makes the output glitching (linebreaks but no return to line-start) on specific conditions (I think it is caused by the python-script waiting for input, while the other prints something).

Is there a better way to output feedback to the user while the program is piped, and only when the other program is waiting for input, that the outputs do not mix.

Comment: you have no other choice than `stderr` since `stdout` is closed for redirection. but `stderr` works very well when properly used. Unix commands use that to display messages/errors while redirected.

Comment: Why not use `/dev/tty`?